# clojure storing vs. using a sequence in expression

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, sequences, lazy-sequences

Helo, In an effort to learn clojure, I have taken an interest in clojure.core functions that act on sequences.  Recently, I noticed some odd behaviour and would like an explaination of the difference between the folling expressions:

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
user=> (reduce + (take-while (partial > 1000) (iterate inc 1)))
499500
```

However, when I store `(iterate inc 1)` with `def` a get an error:

```
user=> (def a (iterate inc 1))
#'user/a
user=> (reduce + (take-while (partial > 1000) (a)))
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Could someone please explain what the difference between storing `iterate inc 1` and using it directly in the expression? I know that `a` is a lazy sequence but am missing something...

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing

```
(reduce + (take-while (partial > 1000) a))
```

`(a)` attempts to call `a`, but it's not a function.

Comment: ahh yes, that explains the error message about a clojure.lang.cons being cast to a clojure.lang.IFn.